# PreventDefault for links in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to disable click on the links and do certain actions , Below code works fine in normal webpage

```
 <a class="list" href="#test"> Click me </a>

 $(document).on("click",".list",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("click");
  log("clicked");
  return false;
});
```

Whereas its opening new tab in chrome extension , I have this code in popup.js of chrome extension. Also below code is working fine in extension

```
<div class="list">hi</div>
```

Comment: 1. Show us how you load scripts in popup.html, 2. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: I never worked on Chrome extensions but could this help? <a class="list" href="#test" target="_self"> Click me </a>  or maybe target="_top"